# Can WordPress Plugin Directory Cache Delay the Upload of Images?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wordpress.org, cache

I've updated my [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jotform-integration/) and I can see the updated text on the plugin page but I don't see any of the screenshots or header image. Is it possible that the cache will move the image files over later? Or did I do something syntactically wrong so they are not showing up?

FYI I did run my [readme file](https://github.com/BFTrick/jotform-integration/blob/d80b86139a712ec18b7a0241c0fbffca6e8a732d/readme.txt) through the [WordPress readme file validator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/validator/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically any plugin changes take 15minutes to be reflected on the plugin's pages in the repo.

Did you upload the screenshots and header image to the /assets/ folder of the repo?

Comment: Looks like your /assets/ folder is in the wrong place.  The /assets/ folder should be in the root of your plugin repo, in the same directory as your /branches/, /tags/ and /trunk/ folders.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It looks like the bash svn-deployment script I found doesn't work very well. I suppose I'll either have to tweak the script or look into git-svn.

Comment: I'll contact the author of the svn-deployment script: http://thereforei.am/2011/04/21/git-to-svn-automated-wordpress-plugin-deployment/

Comment: No problem.  You can also put the screenshot files in your latest tag's root folder.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having some trouble modifying the [deployment script](https://gist.github.com/3767319). Lines 75-78. I'm guessing I'm forgetting some sort of commit?

Comment: It took a while but I figured out the deployment script and moving the files into the right directory worked. Thanks a bunch!